# Convert Language name to Language Code / Country Code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have been working on an application where i need to redirect user to the selected pages that are translated in the respective locale. I have been getting a list of languages from the backend. I need to convert the languages in the language code.
For example:

```
var languageName = ['English', 'Japnese', 'Chinese'];
```

Need to convert them to

```
 ['en-us','ja-jp','zh-cn'];
```

How can i convert the language name to language locale or country code..

Comment: Have you tried anything? Something with `.map()` or just a `for` loop maybe?

Comment: Is "English" `en-us` or `en-uk`? Which dialect of Chinese is "Chinese" exactly? If you're expecting some magic library or API that does this conversion for you, you'd probably fail in some way or another when it comes to these questions. You'll kinda need to define this mapping yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution with a mapping object :

```js
const mappings = {
  'English' : 'en-us',
  'Japanese' : 'ja-jp',
  'Chinese' : 'zh-cn'
};

const languageName = ['English', 'Japanese', 'Chinese'];

const output = languageName.map(lang => mappings[lang]);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object as a mapping and then use a languege you want to get a locale for as a key:

```
const mapping = {
  'English' : 'en-us',
  'Japanese' : 'ja-jp', 
 ... 
};

const desiredLanguage='English';

console.log(mapping[desiredLanguage]) // outputs "en-us"
```